# Problems with using on user computers without ffmeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

My Python program uses ffmpeg. However, if ffmeg was installed on your computer at the time of deployment and is not configured or does not exist in a directory such as the exe file, it will not work normally. If my program has to use ffmpeg while running, I would like to use it in the same folder in the library folder. What should I do?

```
  try:
        for i in sp_text:
            try:
                output_dir = os.path.join('./', '%(playlist_title)s', '%(playlist_index)s. %(title)s.%(ext)s')

                download_list = [
                    i,
                ]

                ydl_opt = {
                    'outtmpl': output_dir,
                    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
                    'postprocessors': [{
                        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                        'preferredquality': '192',
                    }, {'key': 'FFmpegMetadata'}, ],
                }

                with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opt) as ydl:
                    ydl.download(download_list)

                self.lbl.setText('Success!')
            except:
                self.lbl.setText('Error1')
    except:
        self.lbl.setText('Error2')
```

Comment: About the only thing you can do is detect the problem and have your program print out a helpful error message.

Comment: Or distribute ffmpeg with your program.